# What decreases the negative exp effect on jobs

Tags: payday-2

When you have played a contract multiple times like "Firestarter" the experience will start to get a negative modifier on it which can range to quite a high value.

I was wondering if anyone knows how I could decrease the negative effect?

Comment: I've not got any numbers but I believe the help just said do different missions. I assume the penalty decays in some way when not playing that mission but I can't tell you any details.

Comment: the modifier is between -30% and +15% if i recall correctly. If you leave a heist for a while itll gain a positive multiplier on it in a bid to tempt you back to it. As the game adds more heists (i mean look how many we have now as of 16/6/16) the easier it is to play a heist without its multiplier falling, as theres a greater selection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mission type receives an experience penalty for that type of mission when the player **repetitively** plays the mission "too much".

The main way to avoid this is to keep some sort of **rotation of missions** that you like. I personally like Mallcrasher & Jewelry Heist a lot but I accumulate high penalties very quickly. To prevent this, I throw in Four Stores, Rats, and Nightclub (I like keeping things easy). Avoid doing the same mission more than once in a row and you should be okay.

More comments in regards to experience reduction found [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/558750717400426789/).

Answer (score 3):

To add on to what Shelby115 said (I would comment but I don't have enough rep for that), if you do an easier job first and make sure to stealth it, you should get a 10-30% bonus for your next completed contract.